# Problems installing from CD after computer went to sleep while downloading

Tags: system-installation

I downloaded the ISO image for Ubuntu 11.10 and when I tried installing it did not work. It loads until where it shows you how the new Ubuntu looks like. On the desktop and the launcher there are “buttons” for installing and whenever I click on any of those nothing happens no matter how long I wait. But whenever I click on anything else it opens, like the “settings” etc. I don't know what the problem could be and I need your help.

When I was downloading the image my computer went to sleep and I realised after many minutes that it had stopped downloading and was “asleep”. Could this have affected the image to make it not install? Everything else in the disk seems OK except for the install buttons. Help urgently, please.

Comment: Is there an icon on the desktop called "Install" or "Install Ubuntu"? Are you sure nothing happens when you double-click it? At the point where it asks you to choose between "Try Ubuntu" and "Install Ubuntu", did you try the latter?

You can check if your ISO file is corrupt by verifying its MD5sum : see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

Comment: It's probably a semi-broken CD download, you might need to redownload it if the MD5SUMs don't match as prateek says

Answer (score 1):

If you have trouble with the normal install try the [alternate iso's](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/alternative-download)